# What does Shiva's third eye signify?

Tags: vedas, shiva, shiva-purana, symbolism, meditation

I am  not a scholar of Hinduism but I think Shiva's third eye is not a physical eye but it represents the deepest knowledge of nature and its actions.

Shiva reached the deepest state of meditation ever known and that's why people describe him as having a third eye as at the time he was able to see the things that normal people can't imagine by mind or through meditation.

Do any scriptures discuss the spiritual significance/symbolism behind the third eye?

Comment: Why not both? All Puranic stories are true both metaphorically & historically.

Comment: Mythology and metaphorically things can be believe. But People will come, argue and not believe many on that. If we can find a things that explain us beside these two term. Will help to explain our coming generation that asking for historical or logical facts on that.

Comment: this is the third eye that is opened by the kundalini for yogic vision. Do a search on this site for third eye.

Comment: So as per my knowledge and understanding it's not third eye it's a knowledge representation in physical form to explain people of that era . As shiva has more knowledge than any one on that time and even today too...

Comment: @YDS : it's near to that but i hope it's not duplicate. No one gave the eye to shiva. It's a representation for common people. I got my some clarity from your link.

Comment: @YDS no longer a duplicate